# How to change position of input field when focused on?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to fix this, but I can't get it to work. I have made this JSFiddle to illustrate my problem:

**https://jsfiddle.net/5rj2jtym/1/**

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <p>Test header</p>
</div>

<input type="text" class="bla" onclick="changepos()" placeholder="put some text here" />
```

And the JS:

```
function changepos() {
    if(document.getElementsByClassName("bla")[0].style.top == '300px'){
        document.getElementsByClassName("bla")[0].style.top="0px";    
    }else{
        document.getElementsByClassName("bla")[0].style.top="300px";  
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve, is that the input field should take the place of the paragraph / header you can see in the fiddle. So when someone focuses / clicks on the input field, the input field should move up (preferably with an animation) so that we have a nice interaction. I tried it with JavaScript, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Please do not roll my edits back. These are good edits, and I will be restoring them. Let's not have to call in a moderator, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd definitely recommend the above CSS method, but just in case you want to use your original JavaScript method.

```js
function changepos(input) {
  input.style.top = "0";
  input.style.transition = "all 0.8s";
}

function resetpos(input) {
  input.style.top = "300px";
  input.style.transition = "all 0.8s";
}
```

```css
input {
  width: 100%;
  top: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <p>
    Test header
  </p>
</div>

<input type="text" class="bla" onfocus="changepos(this)" onblur="resetpos(this)" placeholder="put some text here" />
```

Comment: Question... why is the input field already down, initially? I would expect the opposite? Anyway, thanks man!

Comment: I'd always suggest placing all elements on the page using standard HTML and CSS, and then using JavaScript to manipulate those elements. A small amount of user's might have JS issues or have it disabled in their browser so it's a good idea to ONLY change these with the JS.

With that in mind, the CSS style set's the position as `top: 300px`. Then the JS sets it to `top: 0` once it is focused and when the user clicks away it will reset back to the `top: 300px` position using the resetpos function. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks mate, appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the css `:focus` Selector?

https://jsfiddle.net/5rj2jtym/12/